# Performance of listening to the same firebase ref multiple times

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Is there a performance issue with listening to the same firebase ref from multiple places? Specifically from calling `on('obj')` on the same ref and obj in different places.

Does firebase use a cache so it only calls the network once for every change?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you attach multiple listeners to the same location, the initial data and changes will be transferred only once.

If you'd like to see what actually gets transferred, have a look at the developer console of Chrome under Network > WS (for Web Sockets). You'll see the connection between the Firebase client and its server and can inspect each frame.